# Incorrect number of results found by XPath

Tags: python-3.x, loops, xpath, lxml, urllib

Actually, the situation is a little more complex.

I'm trying to get data from this example html:

```
<li itemprop="itemListElement">
    <h4>
        <a href="/one" title="page one">one</a>
    </h4>
</li>

<li itemprop="itemListElement">
    <h4>
        <a href="/two" title="page two">two</a>
    </h4>
</li>

<li itemprop="itemListElement">
    <h4>
        <a href="/three" title="page three">three</a>
    </h4>
</li>

<li itemprop="itemListElement">
    <h4>
        <a href="/four" title="page four">four</a>
    </h4>
</li>
```

For now, I'm using Python 3 with `urllib` and `lxml`.
For some reason, the following code doesn't work as expected (Please read the comments)

```
scan = []

example_url = "path/to/html"
page = html.fromstring(urllib.request.urlopen(example_url).read())

# Extracting the li elements from the html
for item in page.xpath("//li[@itemprop='itemListElement']"):
    scan.append(item)

# At this point, the list 'scan' length is 4 (Nothing wrong)

for list_item in scan:
    # This is supposed to print '1' since there's only one match
    # Yet, this actually prints '4' (This is wrong)
    print(len(list_item.xpath("//h4/a")))
```

So as you can see, the first move is to extract the 4 `li` elements and append them to a list, then scan each `li` element for `a` element, but the problem is that each `li` element in `scan` is actually all the four elements.

...Or so I thought.

Doing a quick debugging, I found that the `scan` list contains the four `li` elements correctly, so I came to one possible conclusion: There's something wrong with the `for` loop aforementioned above.

```
for list_item in scan:
    # This is supposed to print '1' since there's only one match
    # Yet, this actually prints '4' (This is wrong)
    print(len(list_item.xpath("//h4/a")))

    # Something is wrong here...
```

The only real problem is that I can't pinpoint the bug. What causes that?

PS: I know, there's an easier way to get the `a` elements from the list, but this is just an example html, the real one contains many more... things.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, when the XPath starts with `//`, it will start searching from the root of the document (which is why it was matching all four of the anchor elements). If you want to search relative to the `li` element, then you would omit the leading slashes:

```
for item in page.xpath("//li[@itemprop='itemListElement']"):
    scan.append(item)

for list_item in scan:
    print(len(list_item.xpath("h4/a")))
```

Of course you can also replace `//` with `.//` so that the search is relative as well:

```
for item in page.xpath("//li[@itemprop='itemListElement']"):
    scan.append(item)

for list_item in scan:
    print(len(list_item.xpath(".//h4/a")))
```

Here is a relevant quote taken from the specification:

> [**2.5 Abbreviated Syntax**](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#path-abbrev)
>
> `//` is short for `/descendant-or-self::node()/`. For example, `//para` is short for `/descendant-or-self::node()/child::para` and so will select any `para` element in the document (even a `para` element that is a document element will be selected by `//para` since the document element node is a child of the root node); `div//para` is short for `div/descendant-or-self::node()/child::para` and so will select all `para` descendants of div children.

Comment: `.//` solved the problem, thank you for your answer. But why it did? First, we load a page and get its html, then extract `li` tags and put **each one** in a list. Why using `//` would make any difference? Since at the second `for` loop we iterate over each one of the `li` tags, there should be one and only `h4` and therefore `a` tag. EDIT: Could it be that even after extracting the `li` tags, we still have the whole html? This could be the real culprit.

Comment: @Eekan - Correct, even after extracting the `li` tags, the XPath query still has access to the whole HTML. In your example, `list_item` is a reference to the `li` elements. I believe the reason it's done like this is because XPath allows you to traverse up the tree and select a parent element. This means that the `li` would have to be a reference so that the other elements up the tree are still available for more complex querying.

Comment: Thanks, mate. I guess I've grasped XPath better.

Answer (score 0):

```
print(len(list_item.xpath(".//h4/a")))
```

`//` means `/descendant-or-self::node()`
it starts with `/`, so it will search from root node of the document.

use `.` to point the current context node is `list_item`, not the whole document